# How to trigger the right scroll in selenium in SportBookReview.com?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, web-scraping

I'm web scraping the following url:

https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nba-basketball/money-line/?date=20190311

There is a right scroll button on the rightmost part of the page, but when inspecting its source, I do not find any link or javascript on click associated with the button. Here is my question:

1. Without a javascript or a link, what controls the behavior of clicking on the right-scroll button? Or is there any event listener on the button that I am not aware of (very beginner knowledge of javascript)
2. If I want to scrape the page, I can scroll to the right by simulating a click in selenium like "button.click()". However, I find that is error prone. For example, there are always ClickInterceptedException with Chrome webdriver. Is there a better way of scraping content to the right of the page?

Answer (score 0):

To click on right arrow button use while loop and check if button exists.if yes it will click() once it can't find jumps out of the loop.

```
driver.get("https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nba-basketball/money-line/?date=20190311");
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,40);

 while(true)
    {
     if (wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("(//i[@class='sbr-icon-chevron-right'])[1]"))).size()>0)
    {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//i[@class='sbr-icon-chevron-right'])[1]")).click();

    }
    else
    {
         break;
     }

    }
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't think this is the same as what I wanted. If you look at the page, the scroll-to-right button does things that cannot be done by scrolling with mouse wheels.

Comment: @DiveIntoML : I hope you after this solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is just my two cents on the matter and I would say my javascript skills are average and simplistic. I do use javascript, webdriver, and selenium a lot though.

What KunduK wrote `use while loop and check if button exists.if yes it will click() once it can't find jumps out of the loop` is basically right if I understand your initial problem (I don't fully understand your questions enough to answer). I'm just here to provide a solution that I've tested and works.

```
const url2 = "https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nba-basketball/money-line/?date=20190311"
async function main(){
    const client = webdriverio.remote({
        desiredCapabilities: {
            browserName: "chrome",
            deprecationWarnings: "false"
        }
    })
    await client.init();
    await client.url(url2);
    await client.waitForVisible("#bettingOddsGridContainer", 10000);
    await client.click("#bettingOddsGridContainer > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > i");
}
```

That will click the right arrow in the first row and let it move forward. I didn't understand your question as the arrow appears as an element in the DOM and allows the user to manipulate it.
You can add a

```
let rightArrowExist = await client.isExisting("#bettingOddsGridContainer > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > i");
```

if you want. It will come out as true while the arrow is there. I can scrolled all the way to the right and confirm the arrow disappears once you reach the end.